# C# MVC Access Action Param from controller Initialization

Tags: c#, post, httpcontext

If I have a controller with HTTP POST action with once or several parameters like this:

```
//[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ajaxbuscarope(string texto="")
{

}
```

How could I access to "texto" parameter directly from the controller Initialization...

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext 
requestContext)
{

    var texto=???
}
```

I can access the Get parameters using this...

```
var url_with_params=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

But this is not working with post request with declared parameters

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection post = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
```

Comment: why do you need it in `Initialize`?

Comment: Because I need to register all the activity in the controller (monitoring). No matter the action I need to save the route, get param and post param. Even all controllers in the App have this behaviour.

Comment: maybe you should use action filter for this?

Comment: I have found the solution!!!!!

Comment: HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);

     var requestFromPost = Encoding.Default.GetString(HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.TotalBytes));
   //this is very important because if you dont add this the parameters are not visibles in the action
    request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);

var requestFromPost = Encoding.Default.GetString(HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.TotalBytes));
//this is very important to have the parameters available in the action
request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```